# javascript image uploader dont display the selected image

Tags: javascript

I have a input type file, which should select an image and validate the file extention to see if its really an image.

When I select the image it should display it, but it doesnt.

Can someone help me?

this is the code:

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="file"  id="imageupload" onchange="return ValidateFileUpload()" />
    <img src="#" id="image">
</form>

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    function ValidateFileUpload() {
        var fuData = document.getElementById('imageupload');
        var FileUploadPath = fuData.value;

        if (FileUploadPath == '') {
            alert("Please upload an image");

        } else {
            var Extension = FileUploadPath.substring(FileUploadPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();


            if (Extension == "gif" || Extension == "png" || Extension == "bmp" || Extension == "jpeg" || Extension == "jpg") {

                if (fuData.files && fuData.files[0]) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onload = function(e) {
                        $('#image').attr('src', e.target.result);
                    }

                    reader.readAsDataURL(fuData.files[0]);
                }

            } 

            else {
                alert("Allowed file types: GIF, PNG, JPG, JPEG and BMP. ");

            }
        }
    }
</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of your codes are working, except that onchange="..." is not recognized in chrome. 
So I changed your codes to setup event handler via jQuery to make it work.

```
$("document").ready(function(){

    $("#imageupload").change(function() {

        ValidateFileUpload();
    });
});
```

See demo here http://jsfiddle.net/q53qm/4/

Answer (score 0):

It's working at a google chrom, firefox, not working with IE

Note that `fuData.files`  will only work in browsers that support the File API. For IE9 and earlier, for example, you only have access to the file name. The input element has no files property in non-File API browsers.

Comment: for more info about file uploading go to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList